# Finding the determinant of a $3*3$ matrix that was developed using LaGrangian multiplier to optimize the surface area of a conical frustum

Tags: determinant, math-software

[This is the matrix I wrote down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifjyw.png)
I'm struggling to find its determinant as by hand it would be impractical and would take a lot of time, is there any online calculator or a way to find it quickly, if so how, thanks.

Comment: Why in the world are you writing a matrix? This is far from a system of linear equations.

Comment: @TedShifrin because i saw it being done here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024363/optimizing-a-conical-frustum-using-partial-differentiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Symbolab, I got:

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}\pi \left(1+sin\left(\theta \right)\right)&\pi \left(1+sin\left(\theta \right)\right)&\frac{1}{6}\pi \:\:cos\left(\theta \right)\left(ysin\left(\theta \right)+3x\right)\\ \:\:\:\pi \:&0&\frac{1}{6}\pi \:\:cos\left(\theta \right)\left(3x-ysin\left(\theta \right)\right)\\ \:\:\:0&\pi \:\:cos\left(\theta \right)&\frac{1}{24}\pi \left(6x^2+y^2-y^2cos\left(2\theta \right)\right)\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=-\frac{\pi ^3x\cos ^2\left(θ\right)\sin \left(θ\right)}{2}+\frac{2\pi ^3y\cos ^2\left(θ\right)\sin \left(θ\right)+\pi ^3y\cos ^2\left(θ\right)\sin ^2\left(θ\right)}{6}+\frac{-\pi ^3y^2+\pi ^3y^2\cos \left(2θ\right)-\pi ^3y^2\sin \left(θ\right)+\pi ^3y^2\sin \left(θ\right)\cos \left(2θ\right)}{24}+\frac{-\pi ^3x^2-\pi ^3x^2\sin \left(θ\right)}{4}$$